# Send request to API controller devise_token_auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

My MembersController is in app/controllers/api/v1/members_controller:

```
class API::V1::MembersController < ApplicationController
include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
***before_action :authenticate_api_v1_member!***
  def index
    @members = Member.all
    render json: @members
  end
```

In my member.rb

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules.
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
end
```

In my member_serializer:

```
class MemberSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :email, :uid, :name, :nickname, :admin
end
```

My question is:
  If I don't have the line before_action :authenticate_api_v1_member!, I can send request from Postman to '/api/v1/members' and I can get the JSON respond.[error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7IYq.png)

> Blockquote

If I have the line above, with header include 'uid, client, access-token', I get the error below: 
header 'client, access-token', the error is below:
[error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXpCM.png)

How can I send request to the 'members#index' with devise_token_auth??? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I used rails g devise_token_auth:install Member member_auth to generate the member, devise_token_auth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem and If anybody face the same issue, contact me by post an comment on this and I'll post answer.